# Get status code in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to cache some request to static files which can be served by nginx directly by middleware.

Core codes:

```
function PageCache(config) {
    config = config || {};
    root = config.path || os.tmpdir() + "/_viewcache__";
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var key = req.originalUrl || req.url;
        var shouldCache = key.indexOf("search") < 0;
        if (shouldCache) {
            var extension = path.extname(key).substring(1);
            if (extension) {

            } else {
                if (key.match(/\/$/)) {
                    key = key + "index.html"
                } else {
                    key = key + ".html";
                }
            }

            var cacheFilePath = path.resolve(root + key)
            try {

                res.sendResponse = res.send;
                res.send = function (body) {
                    res.sendResponse(body);

                    // cache file only if response status code is 200
                    cacheFile(cacheFilePath, body);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
        next()
    }
}
```

However I found that all the response are cached no matter the status code, while respone with code 404,410,500 or something else should not be cached.

But I can not find any api like `res.status` or `res.get('status')` which can be used to get the status code of the current request.

Any alternative solution?

Comment: status code is specificed for response not for request when you want to send response can use `res.status(404).send("ok")` for example

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can override `res.end` event that is being called whenever response ends. You can get `statusCode` of response whenever response ends.

Hope it helps you

```
var end = res.end;

res.end  = function(chunk, encoding) {
     if(res.statusCode == 200){
         // cache file only if response status code is 200
         cacheFile(cacheFilePath, body);
     }

     res.end = end;
     res.end(chunk, encoding);
};
```

Comment: That helps.  Why the hell isn't `res.statusCode` in the Express docs?  That would have saved me the trouble...

Comment: UPDATE: For some reason, `res.statusCode` is always yielding a `200`, even when my app returns a 304 or 404.

Comment: @odigity It works for me. I use a different implementation though: `res.status(404).send(); if (res.headersSent) console.log(res.statusCode);`

Comment: I use the same implementation as Jake and still have the issue it's always yielding `200`. I solved it with the package `on-finished`

Answer (score 1):

you can use **res.statusCode** to the get the status.

Comment: res.statusCode always returns 200 in the middleware.

Comment: @Jompis you can use express-interceptor to get the actual response. you will see that the res.statusCode has the actual status code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [on-finished](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-finished) middleware to make sure response headers are sent and then read the status

```
var onFinished = require('on-finished')


onFinished(res, function (err, res) {
   // read res.statusCode here
})
```